# MySQL, operation DELETE

Tags: mysql, table, delete

I have:

```
DELETE FROM songs 
WHERE songs.id_album = album.id 
AND album.id_band =16`
```

> Error: #1054 - Unbekanntes Tabellenfeld 'album.id' in where clause.

Table `album` exists, field `id` too, 100%.

Where is error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `album` table because it isn't actually included in the query. (in the `FROM` clause). You need to do this instead:

```
DELETE songs.*
FROM songs
  JOIN album 
    ON album.id = songs.id_album
 WHERE album.id_band = 16
```

See the section titled *Multi-Table Deletes* in the documentation for [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

Alternatively, you could use [WHERE EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
DELETE FROM songs
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM album 
                WHERE id_band = 16 
                  AND id = songs.id_album)
```